# angular2 - make a variable more variable

Tags: javascript, angular, variables, typescript

So I am not sure whether the question is stupid or not, however I feel like my current solution isn't the best.

So I am basically working on a pricing table on the backend. There a 3 different status (plural?). First one is display, second one is edit, third one is 'hidden' and there is a + button to ad a new one.

So now for each column I have prepared three scenarios which I than show/hide with ngIf. I started now working on the actual functions. Like changing when I click buttons and so on.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';


declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: '[packages]',
  templateUrl: './packages.template.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./packages.style.scss']
})
export class PackagesComponent {

  tier1Status = '';
  tier2Status = '';
  tier3Status = '';
  currentTiers = 1;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkTiers();
  }
  checkTiers() {
    if (this.currentTiers === 1) {
      this.tier1Status = 'show';
      this.tier2Status = 'notSetUp';
      this.tier3Status = 'hide';
    }
    else if (this.currentTiers === 2) {
      this.tier1Status = 'show';
      this.tier2Status = 'show';
      this.tier3Status = 'notSetUp';
    }
    else if (this.currentTiers === 3) {
      this.tier1Status = 'show';
      this.tier2Status = 'show';
      this.tier3Status = 'show';
    }
  }
  addTier(tierNumber: number) {
    if (tierNumber === 1) {
      this.tier1Status = 'edit';
    } else if (tierNumber === 2) {
      this.tier2Status = 'edit';
    } else if (tierNumber === 3) {
      this.tier3Status = 'edit';
    }
  }

}
```

So as already mentioned, I am not sure whether this is the best solution. It seems a little complicated. I was wondering whether there is something to make a variabel variabel. Sounds stupid, but basically to have a variabel like tierStatus[x] and when I click a button I always pass which tier is meant.
Sorry I am quiet new to angular2 and typescript/javascript in general.
Maybe be something like this

```
clickEdit (tierNumber: number) {
        tierStatus[tierNumber] = 'edit';
      }
```

Thanks a lot. 
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an enumeration. Enums allow you to define a set of named numeric constants:

```
export enum Tiers {
  Show,
  NotSetup,
  Hide,
  Edit
}
```

So, `Show` will hold `0` as its value, `NotSetup` `1`, and `Hide` `2` and `Edit` `3`.

If you want to give them specific fixed numeric values:

```
export enum Tiers {
  Show = 1,
  NotSetup = 2,
  Hide = 3,
  Edit = 4
}
```

I don't know what tiers 1, 2 and 3 mean, so for display purposes I gave them meaning with an enumeration called Rewards with the values Basic, Classic and Pro.

And then your code would look something like this:

```
  tier1Status = null; // null Or maybe create a Tiers.NotSet value.
  tier2Status = null;
  tier3Status = null;
  currentTiers = Rewards.Basic;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkTiers();
  }

  checkTiers() {
    switch (this.currentTiers) {
      case Rewards.Basic:
        this.tier1Status = Tiers.Show;
        this.tier2Status = Tiers.NotSetup;
        this.tier3Status = Tiers.Hide;
        break;
      case Rewards.Classic:
        this.tier1Status = Tiers.Show;
        this.tier2Status = Tiers.Show;
        this.tier3Status = Tiers.NotSetup;
        break;
      case Rewards.Pro:
        this.tier1Status = Tiers.Show;
        this.tier2Status = Tiers.Show;
        this.tier3Status = Tiers.Show;
        break;
  }

  addTier(tierNumber: Rewards) {
    switch (tierNumber) {
      case Rewards.Basic:
        this.tier1Status = Tiers.Edit;
        break;
      case Rewards.Classic:
        this.tier2Status = Tiers.Edit;
        break;
      case Rewards.Pro:
        this.tier3Status = Tiers.Edit;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Code is untested, of course, I just want to show you a good use case for enums where you can give meaning to your numbers.

[Click Here for more info on enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

You will know what's best for your app and how to get enums to work for you.

If you want to access the string value, you can:
`Tiers[Tiers.show] === 'Show'` => `true`

Updated:
After comment I understand better what you want.
You could use a Map (or a Set), and do something like this:

You could use something like a Map or a Set.

```
// This would be the values of your Tiers enum
Tiers.First
Tiers.Second
Tiers.Third

// And a Status enum
Status.Show
Status.Edit
Status.NotSetup

// Then with a Map, you could do something like this:
const tierStatuses = new Map();
tierStatuses.set(Tiers.First, Status.Show);
tierStatus.set(Tiers.Second, Status.NotSetup);
```

`tierStatus.get(Tiers.First) => Status.Show` where Status.Show could be 0 or another numeric value, depending how you declare it. It returns undefined if not set: e.g. `tierStatus.get('something') => undefined`.

Keep in mind that Maps and Sets are on ES6, so you might need a polyfill or library if you are targeting ES5.

There's also other ways like a custom object or nested array (array of arrays) but that might increase the complexity, not a good trade off vs some extra variables where things are more readable.

Comment: currentTiers =    <-- this provides the number of how many tiers are set up, it starts with 1 and than when click the plus sign it goes up to 3
for me as a beginner, what is the advantage of using instead of if/else?

Comment: I understand better what you meant now. You could use a Map or Set, see extended answer for code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However it feels like the Maps and Sets doesn't seem to make the code much simpler or better right? So the solutions I am currently working with would be fine or would you not recommend keeping it the way it is right now?

Comment: Sometimes, we focus too much on writing less code and adding more magic but then maintainability efforts go up when we go re-visit old code.

I prefer to keep things simple, if they work, are unit testable, readable (plain English) and they work, I keep them. I personally advice to avoid magic at all costs. We can always go back and refactor and make things better adn re-usable as the code evolves.

I would definitively use enums or constants to give meaning to the numeric values, but I think I'd keep the if/else's or switch statements. Really easy to read and know what's going on.